Show Brownian motion with exponential stopping time yields Laplace distribution
On the Wikipedia page for Laplace distribution it says Brownian motion with exponential stopping time yields Laplace distribution. This means if
$$
T \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda), \quad X | T \sim \text{Normal}(0, \sigma^2T)
$$
then we should have
$$ X \sim \text{Laplace}(0,\alpha)$$ for some $\alpha$. One approach is to compute the probability density,
$$
p_X(x) = \int_0^\infty p_{X|T}(x|t) p_T(t) \, dt = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp \left( -\lambda t -\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2 t} \right) \, dt
$$
and show it is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\alpha \exp(-\alpha|x|)$ but I don't see how. Is there a better way?

We assume the stopping time $\tau\sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ is independent of the Brownian motion. An approach with characteristic functions is straightforward:
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\xi B_{\tau}}]&=E[E[e^{i\xi B_{\tau}}|\tau]]\\
&=\int_0^\infty E[e^{i\xi B_{t}}](\lambda e^{-\lambda t})dt\\
&=\lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda +\xi^2/2) t}dt\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda +\xi^2/2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2/(2\lambda)}
\end{aligned}$$

Nice! One correction, to account for the variance it should be $E[e^{i\xi B_t}] = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\xi^2}$, so that $\alpha = \sqrt{2\lambda/\sigma^2}$.

@mdnestor you are correct for the general case, but standard Brownian motion in particular has $\sigma=1$, so $B_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$

@mdnestor for clarity: if you consider $\sigma B_t$, then $E[e^{i\xi \sigma B_t}]=e^{-t\sigma^2\xi^2/2}$.
